# TouchID - Detect new fingerprints added - When does evaluatedPolicyDomainState change?

Tags: ios, swift, touch-id

I'm integrating TouchID into my app. I'm allowing the user to turn it on and off for security reasons. I want it to auto-turn off when the user adds a new fingerprint.
According to Apple, `evaluatedPolicyDomainState`

> This property returns a value only when the canEvaluatePolicy(*:error:) method succeeds for a biometric policy or the evaluatePolicy(*:localizedReason:reply:) method is called and a successful Touch ID authentication is performed. Otherwise, nil is returned.
>
> The returned data is an opaque structure. It can be used to compare with other values returned by this property to determine whether the database of authorized fingerprints has been updated. However, the nature of the change cannot be determined from this data.

However, I'm adding a new fingerprints and `evaluatedPolicyDomainState`  stays the same.

Any idea on how can I make sure `evaluatedPolicyDomainState`  gets updated or if there's any other way of checking if a new fingerprint was added?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

So after struggling for a couple of hours, I finally found the solution.

```
    let context = LAContext()
    context.canEvaluatePolicy(.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: nil)

    if let domainState = context.evaluatedPolicyDomainState
        where domainState == oldDomainState  {
        // Enrollment state the same

    } else {
        // Enrollment state changed

    }
```

Every time you add or delete a fingerprint, the domain state changes. You need to call `canEvaluatePolicy` for `evaluatedPolicyDomainState`to be updated.

Comment: Hi Cristian, We also have this requiremnet in our app.Can you please tell what I should assign to oldDomainState Variable?

Comment: When you first request the user to setup touchID, you will use 'context.evaluatePolicy' . If succeeds, then you get the current policy and save it to oldDomainState.

Comment: I have used kSecAccessControlTouchIDCurrentSet. Now it is working as expected.

Comment: @CristianPena are you saving it to userdefaults?

Comment: I just save a flag to UserDefaults. The proper value is saved in the Keychain.

Comment: You mean adding fingerprint validation for the Keychain?

Comment: yes, i was just wondering from @RXGangam comment, that she used kSecAccessControlTouchIDCurrentSet to detect change

Comment: @CristianPena - I'm trying to detect the old and current state of evaluatedPolicyDomainState but UserDefaults values keep on updating.Pls help on this. How can save the old evaluatedPolicyDomainState values on user default or keychain and how to make a comparison...
variable oldDomainState how to handling from above logic

Answer (score 5):

Below is the solution to convert the data value of **evaluatedPolicyDomainState** into string and store it in keychain. If there is any change of Touch Id, then you just need to compare the value of **evaluatedPolicyDomainState**.

```html
if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: nil) {
    if let domainState = context.evaluatedPolicyDomainState {
        let bData = domainState.base64EncodedData()
        if let decodedString = String(data: bData, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("Decoded Value: \(decodedString)")
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I didn't test this code for Face Id, I believe it will work for both.

Comment: How can i compare the current and old domainState. Pls help on this

Comment: @iCrazyDev, compare them as stings, use `context.evaluatedPolicyDomainState?.base64EncodedString()` for convert.